# Mandrill working fine in my localhost, but not on server. The following SMTP error was encountered: 110 Connection timed out

Tags: codeigniter, email, mandrill

Mandrill working fine in my localhost, but not on server. The following SMTP error was encountered: 110 Connection timed out.I'm working in codeigniter.

Here's my email config file :

```
               $config['mailtype'] = 'html'; 
               $config['charset']  = 'utf-8';
               $config['priority'] = 1;
               $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
               $config['smtp_host'] = 'smtp.mandrillapp.com';
               $config['smtp_port'] = '587';
               $config['smtp_user'] = 'abcdefgh@gmail.com';
               $config['smtp_pass'] = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
```

The mails are received wen sending from localhost. I tried debugger.and i receive the above error. Please help!!! What could be the reason??

Answer (score 0):

i think the port is blocked, try this in any controller:

```
$connection = @fsockopen('smtp.mandrillapp.com', 587);
if (is_resource($connection)){
    echo 'open';
    fclose($connection);
}else{
    echo 'closed';
}
```

i've already had this problem while i'm implementing mandrill on my web app.

Comment: Thanks for replying @Bouhnosaure. Well i tried it.it shows that 587 port is closed. but the server teams are arguing that it is open. I'm totally confused... It's the server issue right?if this port is disabled will normal mails work?? Thanks again.

Comment: I think, the mail port is 25 with php, try to send an email just with email() function for try and tell me !

Comment: mails using normal php functions are working well on this server... But mandril is not working. Are there any special modules to be activated on server?The server teams are asking to provide with the module names.... Thanks again for helping.

Comment: $email_data  = array();
$this->email->subject("Hallo");
$this->email->message("Hallo");
$this->email->from('abcd@ddd', 'Welcome');
$this->email->to('xyz@ddd.com');
$this->email->send();

This is my demo code...I'm very new to codeigniter also.

Comment: Hummmm try to add php cURL extension, mandrill use this for call his own api.

Comment: Thanks for replying @Bouhnosaure. After all the struggle, ther server people said it was there mistake. They hadn't enabld some modules due to security issues.